# Error with method make and symbol LENGTH_LONG in Snackbar

Tags: android, alert, message, android-snackbar

I'm trying to show a snackbar

```
Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But there are two error I don't know why?
1.

> Cannot resolve method 'make(android.view.View, java.lang.String, ?)'

2.

> Cannot resolve symbol 'LENGTH_LONG'

[image]
Can anyone tell me why these errors occur?

**UPDATE**
build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'
}
```

Comment: from where are you calling the snackbar?

Comment: @OBX from a non main activity class.Also these errors occur when I call from the main activity.

Comment: `Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();` can you try this from the activity and see if its resolved?

Comment: @OBX Same result!

Comment: Edit the question with your build.gradle?

Comment: @OBX Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to go for:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
}
```

I've also changed the `compileSdkVersion` & `buildToolsVersion` to the latest version as its best to choose the bleeding edge code. If you do prefer , you can revert to the old one as well. But **DO** note that always keep `compileSdkVersion` & `buildToolsVersion` to be same, ie If you are choosing `23` choose both to be `23` , else it would cause issues.

Now, coming to the `SnackBar`, `SnackBar` is part of Android's design library. And you were compiling `compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'` . Instead use the design library:  `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'` . That should resolve the issue.

Now , from your Activity, invoke the `SnackBar` this way:

```
Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: D:\AndroidSDKTools

Comment: Try clean & rebuild, if not restart the Android studio, Generally you should be asked to install API 25 and sync project, if you can't resolve it still , let me know !

Comment: No there's no link,let me restart Android Studio and tell you the result

Comment: It looks like I haven't installed the platform version 25.Also it takes too long to install that cause my internet speed is not that high Can I use the previous version temporary?

Comment: Yes , you d need to download it. that can be done later. For now you can use `compileSdkVersion 24`  `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"` and try

Comment: Did it fix the issue ?

Comment: Yes bro :) tnx so much

Comment: Another problem!After installing updates I can't run the adb.exe

Comment: this is the error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)

Comment: Fixed after a system restart.